# Subquery processing more rows than necessary

Tags: mysql, indexing, subquery, explain

I am optimising my queries and found something I can't get my head around.

I am using the following query to select a bunch of categories, combining them with an alias from a table containing old and new aliases for categories:

```
SELECT `c`.`id` AS `category.id`, 
    (SELECT `alias`
    FROM `aliases`
    WHERE category_id = c.id
    AND `old` = 0
    AND `lang_id` = 1
    ORDER BY `id` DESC
    LIMIT 1) AS `category.alias`
FROM (`categories` AS c)
WHERE `c`.`status` =  1 AND `c`.`parent_id` =  '11';
```

There are only 2 categories with a value of 11 for `parent_id`, so it should look up 2 categories from the alias table.

[image]

Still if I use `EXPLAIN` it says it has to process 48 rows. The alias table contains 1 entry per category as well (in this case, it can be more). Everything is indexed and if I understand correctly therefore it should find the correct alias immediately.

[image]

Now here's the weird thing. When I don't compare the aliases by the categories from the conditions, but manually by the category ids the query returns, it does process only 1 row, as intended with the index.

So I replace `WHERE category_id = c.id` by `WHERE category_id IN (37, 43)` and the query gets faster:

[image]

The only thing I can think of is that the subquery isn't run over the results from the query but before some filtering is done. Any kind of explanation or help is welcome!

**Edit:** silly me, the `WHERE IN` doesn't work as it doesn't make a unique selection. The question still stands though!

**Create table schema**

```
CREATE TABLE `aliases` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `lang_id` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `alias` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `product_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `brand_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `page_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `campaign_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `old` tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
    KEY `category_id` (`category_id`),
    KEY `page_id` (`page_id`),
    KEY `alias_product_id` (`product_id`,`alias`),
    KEY `alias_category_id` (`category_id`,`alias`),
    KEY `alias_page_id` (`page_id`,`alias`),
    KEY `alias_brand_id` (`brand_id`,`alias`),
    KEY `alias_product_id_old` (`alias`,`product_id`,`old`),
    KEY `alias_category_id_old` (`alias`,`category_id`,`old`),
    KEY `alias_brand_id_old` (`alias`,`brand_id`,`old`),
    KEY `alias_page_id_old` (`alias`,`page_id`,`old`),
    KEY `lang_brand_old` (`lang_id`,`brand_id`,`old`),
    KEY `id_category_id_lang_id_old` (`lang_id`,`old`,`id`,`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=112392 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Comment: Eh?  The schema does not match the `SELECT` -- where are `status` and `parent_id`?

Comment: `status` and `parent_id` are from the main table (`categories`), not the subquery (notice the `c` alias)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ...
    WHERE x=1 AND y=2
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

will be performed in one of several ways.

Since you have not shown us the indexes you have (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`), I will cover some likely cases...

- `INDEX(x, y, id)` -- This can find the last row for that condition, so it does not need to look at more than one row.
- Some other index, or no index:  Scan DESCending from the last `id` checking each row for `x=1 AND y=2`, stopping when (if) such a row is found.
- Some other index, or no index:  Scan the entire table, checking each row for `x=1 AND y=2`; collect them into a temp table; sort by `id`; deliver one row.

Some of the `EXPLAIN` clues:

- Using where -- does not say much
- Using filesort -- it did a sort, apparently for the `ORDER BY`.  (It may have been entirely done in RAM; ignore 'file'.)
- Using index condition (not "Using index") -- this indicates an internal optimization in which it can check the `WHERE` clause more efficiently than it used to in older versions.

Do *not* trust the "Rows" in `EXPLAIN`.  Often they are reasonably correct, but sometimes they are off by orders of magnitude.  Here is a better way to see "how much work" is being done in a rather fast query:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

With the `CREATE TABLE`, I *may* have suggestions on how to improve the index.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Very interesting! It's very hard for me to understand the result of the session status query though.

Comment: I added the CREATE schema. Weird thing is, on my local machine it does use better indexing based on the keys.

Comment: Simple interpretation of `STATUS`:  "some big numbers = slow; all small numbers = fast"

Comment: You have several redundant keys:  If you have `INDEX(a,b,c)`, you do not need `INDEX(a,b)` or `INDEX(a)`.

Comment: If I remove index category_id (INDEX(a)), the EXPLAIN says it has to search 15k rows... It just always uses the category_id index, instead of a more specific one. As this is not the case on my dev environment (it uses PRIMARY as key there), I'll leave it be. I'll wait a little more before accepting your answer, but i think you answered all my questions with your response. Thanks!
Sidenote: it does use the correct index for other searches in the alias table, like for brands or products. Really weird.

Comment: Yes, there are cases where the "statistics" are not quite correct, or the data is skewed in a strange way, or the optimizer "gets it wrong".  5.7 made some improvements in that area; 5.8 will probably make some more improvements.  Meanwhile, the `EXPLAIN` numbers will 'never' be totally correct.